# How to persist a transient to make a command repeatable?

Tags: transient-library, transients

I am converting some of my Hydras to Transient. One of them includes a command with shrinks or enlarges one of my split windows, so I hit it repeatedly until I like my size. How to do this in Transient? The documentation makes it clear that it's possible, but I can't find a place where it explains how. It appears to be related to the `:transient-suffix 'transient--do-stay`, but I can't figure out where to place this to make some of my commands repeatable. Further, it would be nice to set this per-command or per-group, not just on the whole transient. Here is what I'm working with:

```lisp
(transient-define-prefix tsa/transient-window ()
  ;; the following :transient-suffix causes the whole thing to fail at command invocation:
  ;;; command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, tsa/transient-window
  ;;     :transient-suffix 'transient--do-stay
  "Window navigation transient"
  [["Resize"
    ("q" "X←" tsa/move-splitter-left)    
    ("w" "X↓" tsa/move-splitter-down)    
    ("e" "X↑" tsa/move-splitter-up)    
    ("r" "X→" tsa/move-splitter-right)]])
```

Comment: Your example seems to work for me, though you need :transient-suffix after the doc string and not before.

Comment: Ah! yes, silly me. That does it! But it doesn't seem to work for select groups/columns of a transient, such as "only the Resize group". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

`transient` provide a `transient-variable` abstract class.
Inspired by magit `magit--git-variable` which store variables in git config file, I tried to use global elisp variable.

```el
(setq-default my-variable "default")

(defclass my-transient-variable (transient-variable) ())

(cl-defmethod transient-init-value ((obj my-transient-variable))
  (oset obj value (symbol-value (oref obj variable))))

(cl-defmethod transient-format-value ((obj my-transient-variable))
  (let ((v (oref obj value)))
    (if v
        (propertize v 'face 'transient-value)
      (propertize "unset" 'face 'transient-inactive-value))))

(cl-defmethod transient-infix-set ((obj my-transient-variable) user-value)
  (oset obj value user-value)
  (set (oref obj variable) user-value))

(transient-define-argument my-option-argument ()
  :description "My Option"
  :class 'my-transient-variable
  :key "d"
  :variable 'my-variable
  :prompt "My option: "
  )

(transient-define-prefix my-command-transiant ()
  "Test"
  ["Arguments"
   (my-option-argument)]
  ["Commands"
   ("c" "run"     my-command-run)
   ("q" "Quit"    transient-quit-one)])

(defun my-command-run (&optional args)
  (interactive (transient-args 'my-command-transiant))
  (message (format "My option value: %s" my-variable)))
```